# Preview webpage in progressive webapp?

Tags: http-headers, progressive-web-apps, x-frame-options, websecurity

Can PWAs act as browsers? Or more technically: Does the PWA concept allow displaying previews of other webpages, regardless of their X-frame-options or similar settings?

I am not currently persueing specific ideas myself; Rather I am interested into whether the current technology would allow to convert apps such as Feedly, whose native apps allow viewing webpages without leaving the app, to PWAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the PWA concept allow displaying previews of other webpages, regardless of their X-frame-options or similar settings?

No. Standard web security rules still apply.